# R List of Dataframes - How to select certain columns in every entry?

Tags: r, list, select, dataframe

I created a list of dataframes with this command, testlist contains the names of the files.

```
data_list = lapply(testlist, read.table)
```

And it looks like this:

```
[[1]]

V1          V2       V3      V4    V5     V6      V7     V8     V9    
1992-01-01  12.062   -1    1.225    1     5.750    1     2.400   0
```

So I have a list of 7 dataframes, each one has the same structure as shown in the example. Every dataframe in the list has 63 columns and now I want to select every 2nd column from the 3rd one on and check weather it is <=0. If yes, I want to remove the column right in front of it.

So for example if column 3 has the -1 values I want to set the entry in column 2 to NA or -999.

I created this:

```
data_list[[1]][, seq (from=3, to=63, by=2)]
```

But this is only working for the 1st entry. When I take away the [[1]] and want to use it for all dataframes in the list like this I get an error message:

```
data_list[, seq (from=3, to=63, by=2)]
Error in data_list[, seq(from = 3, to = 63, by = 2)] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

How can I select every dataframe in the list? And how can I remove the column in front of the selected ones when they have a values smaller or equal than 0?

Here is a testlist, that has the structure of mine:

```
V1= c("20000608", "20000609", "20000610", "20000611", "20000612", "20000613")
V2= seq(5, 30, length=6)
V3= rep(c(-1,0,1), times=2) 
V4= seq(10, 60, length=6) 
V5= rep(c(1,-1,0), times=2) 

testframe1 = data.frame(V1, V2, V3, V4, V5) 

x1= c("20030608", "20100609", "20060610", "20040611", "20009612", "20002613")
x2= seq(4, 80, length=6)
x3= rep(c(0,-1,1), times=2) 
x4= seq(3, 60, length=6) 
x5= rep(c(-1,1,0), times=2) 

testframe2 = data.frame(V1=x1, V2=x2, V3=x3, V4=x4, V5=x5) 

a1= c("20030602", "20100606", "20060610", "20040511", "20007612", "20002624")
a2= seq(7, 133, length=6)
a3= rep(c(-1,0,1), times=2) 
a4= seq(9, 47, length=6) 
a5= rep(c(1,0,-1), times=2) 

testframe3 = data.frame(V1=a1, V2=a2, V3=a3, V4=a4, V5=a5) 

list = list(testframe1, testframe2, testframe3)
```

Comment: You should use `dput` on your data and post it so people have something to play with. Here is something that might work but I'm not going to create the data to test it. `for(i in 1:length(data_list)){if(data_list[[i]][,3]<=0) data_list[[i]]<-data_list[[i]][,-2]}`

Comment: I dont really get it how to use dput. The files I have are huge, so I think its a better idea to create a testset. I will add one! Oh and the code doesnt work, I get this error message: Warning messages:
1: In if (data_list[[i]][, 3] <= 0) data_list[[i]] <- data_list[[i]][,  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me.

```
for(i in 1:length(data_list)){
x2=data_list[[i]][,c(FALSE,TRUE)]
x2[data_list[[i]][,c(TRUE,FALSE)][,-1]<=0]<-NA
data_list[[i]][,c(FALSE,TRUE)]<-x2}
```

You can also just use `lapply`.

```
lapply(data_list,function(x){
x2=x[,c(FALSE,TRUE)]
x2[x[,c(TRUE,FALSE)][,-1]<=0]<-NA
x[,c(FALSE,TRUE)]<-x2
x})
```

**Result**

```
>data_list
[[1]]
        V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1 20000608 NA -1 10  1
2 20000609 NA  0 NA -1
3 20000610 15  1 NA  0
4 20000611 NA -1 40  1
5 20000612 NA  0 NA -1
6 20000613 30  1 NA  0

[[2]]
        V1   V2 V3   V4 V5
1 20030608   NA  0   NA -1
2 20100609   NA -1 14.4  1
3 20060610 34.4  1   NA  0
4 20040611   NA  0   NA -1
5 20009612   NA -1 48.6  1
6 20002613 80.0  1   NA  0

[[3]]
        V1    V2 V3   V4 V5
1 20030602    NA -1  9.0  1
2 20100606    NA  0   NA  0
3 20060610  57.4  1   NA -1
4 20040511    NA -1 31.8  1
5 20007612    NA  0   NA  0
6 20002624 133.0  1   NA -1
```

Comment: Thank you! That really works! I would have never managed that by myself! Thanks for your help!